# Android: Is it possible to connect to a server without configuring router's NAT?

Tags: android, tcp, router, nat

I'm trying to find a way to establish a TCP connection (socket) between an Android device and a server without having to setup server's router NAT.

**ANDROID DEVICE -> INTERNET -> ROUTER (with fixed external ip address) -> SERVER (with fixed LAN ip address)**

Something like: "*connect to 200.111.222.333 (with local address 192.168.1.1) on port 5000*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to use TURN or STUN or some other intermediate connectivity solution, but in general it isn't possible to declaratively specify an internal target behind a NAT device for a generic TCP connection on any platform (not just Android).